# How to catch exceptions in twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm running a pretty simple server in Python using Twisted. When I try to run two at the same time, this exception occurs:

```
twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on 127.0.0.1:5050: [Errno 98] Address already in use.
```

It makes a lot of sense. How can I catch this exception?

I'd simply like to terminate the reactor and shut everything down if an existing server is running. Otherwise, I get the exception and it just hangs indefinitely until I kill the process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use an [error handler callback](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#auto4), an `errBack` in Twisted lingo. You can add one to a `Deferred` using the `addErrback` method.

Comment: How do I get a deferred to attach to? Is there a main loop deferred for me to attach to?

Comment: Where is the exception arising? If it comes in the reactor.run() method, then there's no deferred to attach an errback to, but the except block *should* be executed. What's your code?